# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CompanyID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been reading StackOverflow but nothing has really been able to help me with this. I'm working on a position model that has SelectLists for a fields from a couple other models, yet every time I try and save I get the error:

**"An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code**

**Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CompanyID'."**

Here's the relevant code from my view:

*Views/Position/Create.cshtml*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Company</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", (SelectList)ViewBag.AllCompanies, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant code from my controller:

*Controllers/PositionController.cs*

```
        // GET: /Position/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            //create query to find all committees
            var query = from m in db.Majors
                        orderby m.Major
                        select m;
            //execute query and store in list
            List<Majors> allMajors = query.ToList();

            //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
            SelectList allMajorsList = new SelectList(allMajors, "MajorID", "Major");

            ViewBag.AllMajors = allMajorsList;

            //create query to find all committees
            var query2 = from c in db.Companies
                        orderby c.CompanyName
                        select c;
            //execute query and store in list
            List<Company> allCompanies = query2.ToList();

            //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
            SelectList allCompaniesList = new SelectList(allCompanies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");

            ViewBag.AllCompanies = allCompaniesList;

            //create query to find all committees
            var query3 = from i in db.Industries
                         orderby i.IndustryName
                         select i;
            //execute query and store in list
            List<Industry> allIndustries = query3.ToList();

            //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
            SelectList allIndustriesList = new SelectList(allIndustries, "IndustryID", "IndustryName");

            ViewBag.AllIndustries = allIndustriesList;

            return View();
        }

    // POST: /Position/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PositionID,PositionTitle,PositionType,PositionLocation,PositionDeadline,PositionDescription")] Position position, int[] SelectedMajors, Int32 CompanyID, Int32 IndustryID)
    {
        //find selected committee
        Company SelectedCompany = db.Companies.Find(CompanyID);
        Industry SelectedIndustry = db.Industries.Find(IndustryID);

        //associate committee with event
        position.PositionCompany = SelectedCompany;
        position.PositionIndustry = SelectedIndustry;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //if there are majors to add, add them
            if (SelectedMajors != null)
            {
                foreach (int MajorId in SelectedMajors)
                {
                    Majors majorToAdd = db.Majors.Find(MajorId);
                    position.ApplicableMajors.Add(majorToAdd);
                }
            }

            db.Positions.Add(position);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(position);
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change the name of the `ViewBag.AllCompanies` to  `ViewBag.CompanyID`

Comment: @DCruz22 Just tried it - getting the same error :/

Comment: Why dont you use a strongly-typed view?

Comment: I think you're missing a parameter. Use `@Html.DropDownList("CompanyID", (SelectList)ViewBag.AllCompanies, "Select a company" new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: Slightly different message because you use `DropDownList()` rather than `DropDownListFor()` but otherwise identical to the dupe.

Comment: Answer in the dupe seems off to me.. OP's problem only occurs after POST `yet every time I try and save I get the error:`.. its pretty simple fix.. difference here is OP is using ViewBag i suppose

Comment: @JamieD77, The answer in the dupe is exactly the problem. The view is returned (because `ModelState is invalid`) and OP has not repopulated the `SelectList`(s)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i guess i can see that, but that answer seems convoluted compared to other answers i've seen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is most likely false.. and you're not resetting the ViewBag values when you return View from your POST..

If the ViewBag values are null, then the view will look for something in your ViewData that matches the name of the property and that's why you're getting that error.  If you comment all of the code in your [HttpGet] action and just return View there, you will get the same errors.

You should try moving all of this code into a private void..

```
private void LoadViewBag() 
{
        //create query to find all committees
        var query = from m in db.Majors
                    orderby m.Major
                    select m;
        //execute query and store in list
        List<Majors> allMajors = query.ToList();

        //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
        SelectList allMajorsList = new SelectList(allMajors, "MajorID", "Major");

        ViewBag.AllMajors = allMajorsList;

        //create query to find all committees
        var query2 = from c in db.Companies
                    orderby c.CompanyName
                    select c;
        //execute query and store in list
        List<Company> allCompanies = query2.ToList();

        //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
        SelectList allCompaniesList = new SelectList(allCompanies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");

        ViewBag.AllCompanies = allCompaniesList;

        //create query to find all committees
        var query3 = from i in db.Industries
                     orderby i.IndustryName
                     select i;
        //execute query and store in list
        List<Industry> allIndustries = query3.ToList();

        //convert list to select list format needed for HTML
        SelectList allIndustriesList = new SelectList(allIndustries, "IndustryID", "IndustryName");

        ViewBag.AllIndustries = allIndustriesList;
}
```

Then change your GET Action to

```
    // GET: /Position/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        LoadViewBag();
        return View();
    }
```

Then change your Post action to

```
// POST: /Position/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PositionID,PositionTitle,PositionType,PositionLocation,PositionDeadline,PositionDescription")] Position position, int[] SelectedMajors, Int32 CompanyID, Int32 IndustryID)
{
    //find selected committee
    Company SelectedCompany = db.Companies.Find(CompanyID);
    Industry SelectedIndustry = db.Industries.Find(IndustryID);

    //associate committee with event
    position.PositionCompany = SelectedCompany;
    position.PositionIndustry = SelectedIndustry;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //if there are majors to add, add them
        if (SelectedMajors != null)
        {
            foreach (int MajorId in SelectedMajors)
            {
                Majors majorToAdd = db.Majors.Find(MajorId);
                position.ApplicableMajors.Add(majorToAdd);
            }
        }

        db.Positions.Add(position);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    LoadViewBag();
    return View(position);
}
```